# What would international politics look like in a world where the supernatural is just apart of life?

Tags: society, politics, super-powers

This question assumes the world where religious miracles are common place and spirits visit the Earth. For more detail, see [How to explain atheism in a world where religious miracles are commonplace and spirits visit earth?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44366/how-to-explain-atheism-in-a-world-where-religious-miracles-are-commonplace-and-s)

Once the governments eventually accept that they live in a world where miracles happen and spirits come to say hi every once in a while, how will international politics change?

Comment: Please change your question title to actually describe the question. Something like "What would international politics look like with telekinesis and mind reading?" Your current title gives no understanding to viewers, and is similar to awful clickbait like "You would NEVER believe what this kid does next!!"

Comment: I also don't quite understand the question. You verbally reference a previous question, but do not link to it (I assume it was the "how can people deny miracles in a world where they exist?"-kind of thing). It is unclear what "above" refers to, the question itself seems to have no structure. However, given the specifications, I don't think there is one single good answer to be given. How do miracles happen? How far do the mind-reading capabilities go, can they be fooled? The role religion(s) plays is also unclear to me.

Comment: @InstantMuffin I have made some changes, is it any better

Comment: @Mirror318  I made some changes any better.

Comment: This is basically a "what would the impact on X be if there were people with super powers" question, but with a very vague description of the powers, how strong they are, and how many people have them. On the other side, "international politics" is an extremely broad topic. I don't think this can be answered without giving more specifics about the scenario and narrowing down the question.

Comment: Game of Thrones, anyone?

Comment: I don't necessarily see a link between miracles and international politics...unless you are telling us one exists (which you have not)

Comment: @James see my other question

Comment: Without you telling us how international politics are impacted we really can't do anything but guess...not to mention that is a really really really big topic.  Are you talking about Sino-Korean relations, US-Canadian relations, German-Zimbabwe relations?  There's just no way to answer this without a 7000 page treatise that would frankly be mostly conjecture anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what supposedly happened when miracles were allegedly working before. Yeah, let's use the Bible as evidence.

Note: As a person born in a Roman Catholic environment, I can only speak for what happens in the Bible my parents gave to me. But I'm pretty sure this applies equally to any myth.

In the Bible, miracles shape things. I mean. Political leaders are **nothing**. Take the [Plagues of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Egypt): the most powerful country can be on its knees in a matter of days.

Basically, what was before dependent on masses or big administrations may now depend on the whims of a passing-by spirit or the will of a few organized miracle-doers.

What would happen? Pretty much anything you want. I mean, you haven't given any limitations to miracles. So I'm assuming everybody has a nuclear bomb in one hand and a "resurrection bomb" in the other. Everyone may die and come back, those that come on top would be those that manage to make themselves unattainable while maintaining a maximum chaos between other factions.

As a side note, governments would probably be overwhelmed way sooner that your time line expects. I mean, people coming back to life is not something the government would **not** notice. Governments tend to keep track on who is alive or dead on their land. Same for just healing. And that is just the immediate good stuff that may happen. A few high magnitude earthquakes or a permanent hurricane season could not be contained for 40 years.

Now, I'm gonna assume from your previous question that religion as taken a bit of growth from the phenomenon. We now have a motor for stability, with the actual capacity to do stuff (you did not precise whether religious people could do more than non-religious people, but that seemed implied in your questions).

My guess is, political leader are going to give a lot of power to their favorite church. I mean, if they are the most prepared for what the world is, why not handle things in a medieval style, with a religion-approved leader? Things seem to have taken a medieval turn anyway.

And, from my (restricted) historical perspective, I bet almost no religious leader would refuse to take power.

Comment: I find the bible argument to be quite circumstantial. That same bible (the new testament though) shows how Jesus walks around, performing miracles and ending up being screwed over by governments and the law, being crucified in the end. While in the moment Jesus passes the sky darkens and some Romans realize what they have done, they do not suffer any consequences. Quite the opposite, as in the last moments Jesus himself asks for forgiveness for them.

Comment: Of course, a loving and caring miracle performer would not cause the mayhem I'm talking about. My point mainly is what "unlimited miracles" may do in the hands willing to use them. As there are a lot of people with miracle capabilities in that world, I am fairly confident that those problems would happen.

Comment: @InstantMuffin  Of course he forgave them in his on words in john he said he was not in the world to judge the world but to save it. That would of course include the even those that killed him.

Comment: @PatJ It would probably vary from religion to religion and from miracle work to miracle work. I don't see all of them taken direct political power (but I am pretty sure a lot of them would though) but regardless of direct power any miracle worker will have indirect power. People though out history tend to take the opinions of who they believe to work miracles seriously.  This would give the miracle works a type of power weather they wanted it our not.

Comment: @PatJ congratulations on being the first to comment.

Comment: @Bryan McClure If I understand it correctly, the afterlife didn't exist before Jesus' sacrifice, and that was his purpose by "saving" the world. This however implies that before that, no one was being judged for his sins and disallowed to enter paradise. So yes, he wanted to save the world, but no, he in fact makes the Last Judgment possible, thereby not forgiving some people for their sins. What I want to say is that bible references as arguments are completely unusable, because its a) a collection of many books and re-tellings and b) is insanely contradictory.

Comment: @InstantMuffin I'm just quoting John man If you have something against what I said take up with him.  I was take out the nature of Jesus anyone not arguing about the afterlife.

Comment: @InstantMuffin Taking a afterlife should be confusing. It a whole different dimension. Can you imagine trying to explain the third dimension to people who have only lived in two. Or how about explain a ex box to a pre industrialist.  They would probably be very confused by the end of it.  So we should not be surprised that what we know about the afterlife is confusing.

Comment: @InstantMuffin It like the story of the blind men and elephant. Group of blind men stubble upon a elephant.  First one grabs his truck and says the element is like a large snake. Second touches the side and say the first is wrong the elephant is like wall and so forth.

Comment: @InstantMuffin Also keep in mind that God is out side of time itself and if He is outside of time then presumably so is the afterlife. If some is exist out side of time itself then it is theoretically it could exist long before it was created.

Comment: @Bryan McClure I'm not sure what this lead to, but in an effort to try to make my stance more understandable: I don't see how a Bible quote can count as an argument, because for each bible quote, there is one that says the opposite. I'm generally approve PatJ's answer, however Bible stuff is always a bad example because of its contradictory nature.

Comment: @InstantMuffin I was not trying to make a pointed about the question or PatJ answer's to it, which I consider to be pretty good answer. I wasn't nor am now try to argue with him or with you. In you first comment you brought up something while it was unrelated to question I though was interesting so I comment my thoughts on the subject. If something said wrong I apologies it was not my intent.

Comment: You guys need a beer and a couch. Theology always seems above me. :-)